# Backslash on Include directories with pkg-config on Mac OS Lion

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, openssl, pkg-config

Good evening everybody,

I have virtually no experience with pkg-config but it seems that I will have to use it in working with openssl. Im on a Mac, which might be of some importance.

The problem is:

- i compile my testing program with

  ```
  cc test.cc `pkg-config --libs --cflags openssl` -o test
  ```
- i have compiled openssl and installed it in ~/openssl afterwards adding ~/openssl/lib/pkgconfig to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH
- since I want to use the newest version instead of the preinstalled one, I specify the options with every compilation
- the result of running `pkg-config --libs` or `pkg-config --cflags openssl` is `-L\~/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto`

This begs the question for me why there is a backsash and whether my compiled version is used or the preinstalled one and if the first one is the case how i could possibly fix this...

Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The expansion of `~` to your home directory only occurs in certain circumstances. Basically, it's the shell that's doing it. If a program or a file API sees the tilde, it is interpreted as a literal; it's not expanded.

Use `$HOME` when setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` instead, as in `$HOME/openssl`.